# How to do GetButton in Unity's new Input System

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to unity and game dev and I am following a tutorial on YouTube about implementing better jumping in Unity2D by using multipliers for jumping and falling (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7KiK0Aqtmzc&t=635s). This is the code used in the tutorial:

```cs
public float fallMultiplier = 2.5f;
public float lowJumpMultiplier = 2f;

Rigidbody2D rb2D;

void Awake()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    // Better Jump
    if (rb2D.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        rb2D.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (rb2D.velocity.y > 0 && !Input.GetButton("Jump"))
    {
        rb2D.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

This is my version I tried using with the new Input system:

```cs
public float fallMultiplier = 2.5f;
public float lowJumpMultiplier = 2f;

Rigidbody2D rb2D;

void Awake()
{
    rb2D = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    OnJump();
}

void OnJump(InputValue value)
{
    // Better Jump
    if (rb2D.velocity.y < 0)
    {
        rb2D.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (fallMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    else if (rb2D.velocity.y > 0 && !value.isPressed)
    {
        rb2D.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
}
```

It didn't work. I tried cut and pasting the code in the original PlayerMovement script where the original `void OnJump(InputValue value)` is and even though it gave me no errors, its not modifying the jump using the assigned multipliers. Could someone help with this please?

Sorry if this question/explanation is a bit long-winded.

Answer (score 0):

Before using the new `InputSystem`, you need a list of `InputActions` that can not be found in the above code, create one of them with the help of the images below and select the desired keys.

[image]

[image]

[image]

After performing these steps, click on the Asset created and be sure to check `Generate C# Class`, by processing the code, you can access its parameters in other scripts as well.

[image]

Finally, open your script player and define your inputActions as a variable. This is an example of accessing inputs, consider there are more ways.

```cs
private PlayerControls _controls;
public void Start()
{
    _controls = new PlayerControls();
    _controls.Enable();
}
void Update() => OnJump(_controls.GamePlay.Jump);

void OnJump(InputAction jump)
{
    /*...
    else */ if (rb2D.velocity.y > 0 && !jump.IsPressed())
    {
        rb2D.velocity += Vector2.up * Physics2D.gravity.y * (lowJumpMultiplier - 1) * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    /*...
     */
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for this. I took a long break so sorry for the late thanks and reply. The jumping multiplier and 'better jump# system now works. I am getting an error saying "MissingMethodException: Method 'PlayerMovement.OnJump' not found." but the game currently runs fine and the jump works, apart from the jump spam which i can fix later.

Comment: Solved the error, now the jump is inconsistent, especially when the key is held

Comment: @TheArchitect you can negative condition with `!` operator.